# How to change state on QML

Tags: view, qml, state

I have defined two states in my UI form.
I want to change the state from my main Class.

UI:

```
State {
    name: "State1"
    PropertyChanges { target: signal; color: "green"}
    PropertyChanges { target: flag; state: "FLAG_DOWN"}

    PropertyChanges {
        target: loginButton
        x: 29
        y: 417
    }
}
```

Main:

```
loginButton.onClicked: state.state = "State1"
```

How to change the state from the main?

Comment: If you only have one state defined, how would you "change" it? That makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry for my english, at the end i have 3 or 4 States. But i don't know how to call the state from another file.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already show in the second code snippet how to change states. So where's the problem?

Comment: Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Now you code doesn't describe the problem

Comment: If you want to go back to the - let's call it - "default state", just write `state.state = ""`. Anyhow naming all states would be a good choice...well, also posting well-written and well-thought-out questions would be a good choice...